# how to avoid a files get override on server using git?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have followed following mentioned link & but failed
[Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring)

Here is the situation:
I have download script on server A, which download the files & kept it into the **public/downloads/-files-** folder.  when I run **git push** it overwrites the local files to server.

Ex: 
File status on localhost (Only one file present in git repo for download folder)

```
localhost /downloads/sample.txt
```

File status on server after download script run on server A

```
server A /downloads/a.swf
server A /downloads/b.swf
server A /downloads/c.swf
```

after **git push** run file status on server A

```
server A /downloads/sample.txt
```

What I need is I don't want to get folder files overwrite with sample.txt.

[Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring)

As ref. to above link I tried following things

I implemented gitignore option after removing or uncaching index,   but it remove **/downloads/** dir from server

also I tried

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

but not helped

let me know, if I am doing anything wrong or how to achieve expected result.

thanks in advanced.

Comment: Please guys help me out with above problem.....